# Frames object loop in javascript is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, frames, browser-extension, crossrider

I have written a browser extension with crossrider.com, and need to loop through frames on the page using javascript code,

HTML code. (Main.html)

```
<frameset rows="85,*, 35">
    <frame name="header" src="1.html"    scrolling="no"   frameborder="no" >
    <frame name="body"   src="2.html"    scrolling="auto" frameborder="no">
    <frame name="footer" src="3.html"    scrolling="no"   frameborder="no" >
</frameset>
```

If I write code on the this page ( Main.html) as

```
alert(self.frames.length);
```

it gives me 3, and if I do

```
  for(var k = 0; k < self.frames.length ; k++)
    { 
      var obj = self.frames[k];
      // this obj is always object. 
      //and I could do further operation on this as obj.document ,
    }
```

however If you write crossrider extension and do same as

```
appAPI.ready(function($){

var framesLength = self.frames.length; //it also gives 3
//but if I do below

for(var k = 0; k < self.frames.length ; k++)
    { 
      var obj = self.frames[k];
      // **this obj is always undefined.**
    }

});
```

Any help or direction towards solution is appreciated.

Comment: can you give a url where you have tried executing the extension on ? (a url with framesets like in your example code)

Comment: The extension is installed on browser locally and I am testing local application therefore I dont have URL for this, however if you go to crossrider and copy alert self.frames.length and loop through each frame with an alert withing appAPI.ready function. after installing this extension on your browser ( I am testing on IE 9), you will that main.html page with frames gives undefined for all frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did raise question to crossrider team.
[Crossrider-Support-frames-?](https://getsatisfaction.com/crossrider/topics/accessing_frames_using_crossrider_gives_undefined)

The quick answer I got from one of CrossRider employee (Shmueli Ahdut), is that CrossRider API does not support frames however the surprising thing was that

`self.frames.length` 
gave proper alert.

I will be looking into their support for onRequest API with IE. as that way http for frames / ajax request could be monitored easily.